# Como determinar la primera palabra de una cadena java

Tags: java

hola comunidad soy estudiante de programacion y quisiera si podrian apoyarme con este problema

necesito saber la primera palabra y al ultima de una cadena por ejemplo:

`"/*/*/*hola /* -)( perro/*"`

el programa me debería imprimir primera palabra "hola"
ultima  palabra "Perro"
hasta ahora he hecho esto para imprimir la cadena sin caracteres que no sean letra

```
 public void Letras(){
        for (int i=0;i<cuerda.length();i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(cuerda.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.print(cuerda.charAt(i));
            }
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar

Comment: public void Letras(){
     for (int i=0;i<cuerda.length();i++) {
      if (Character.isLetter(cuerda.charAt(i))) {
       System.out.print(cuerda.charAt(i));
       }
      
      }
      
      
     }
hice este metodo para que solo imprima letras descartando los caracteres

Comment: Ese código tienes que ponerlo en tu pregunta, edita la pregunta y pégalo ahi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar en dos pasos, primeramente eliminando los caracteres que no sean vocales ni consonantes:

```
String cadena = "///hola / -)( perro/*";
String cadenaLimpia = "";

//Elimina characteres que no sean vocal ni consonante.
for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) { 
        char ch = cadena.toLowerCase().charAt(i); 
        if(ch == ' ' || ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' ||  (ch >= 'a'&& ch <= 'z')) {                
            cadenaLimpia += cadena.charAt(i);
        }
}
System.out.println(cadenaLimpia);
```

salida:

```
hola   perro
```

Posteriormente obteniendo las palabras de la cadena:

```
  String[] words = cadenaLimpia.split("\\W+");
  for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { 
     System.out.println(words[i]);   
  }
```

salida:

```
hola
perro
```

Comment: amigo tengo un detalle con tu código cuando ingreso una mayúscula este no lo toma en cuenta

Comment: ok, @IsaacPérezPavía ya realice la modificación Issac, revisa.